# How can I use 'in' with an array of tuples in Ecto?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'd like to use the 'in' operator like this :

```elixir
array = [{1, "Jean"}, {2, "Marc"}]
from(x in People,
where: fragment("(?, ?)", x.id, x.first_name) in ^array)
|> Repo.all()`
```

But when I do this, I get this error :

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :lists.zip/2
```

Here is a repo with the code : [ecto_tuples_example](https://github.com/kaisersly/ecto_tuples_example)

You can run `mix test test/models/people_test.exs` to see the errors.

Comment: Added a repo with the code :
[ecto_tuples_example](https://github.com/kaisersly/ecto_tuples_example)

Comment: Does that work in SQL at all?

Comment: In SQL (at least postgres) you can write (columnA, columnB) in ((1,2), (3,4)). Ecto uses = ANY() when you use the in operator.